# How to get archive id of tokbox archived session?

Tags: php, archive, tokbox

I am a php developer and I am using tokbox for sessions. I need to store session on Amazon S3 server. Using the tokbox archive feature I am saving my sessions on S3 server. I have used Archive mode as Always i.e when session is started it driectly archives particular session.

I need to get the archive id of the stored session. How can I fetch it?

Comment: https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample/Archiving this may help you

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at:

https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-PHP-SDK/blob/master/README.md

but, if I understand what you ask, when you call startArchive, just store the result, and query the field id:

```
$archive = $opentok->startArchive($sessionId, $archiveOptions);
$archiveId = $archive->id;
```

Comment: Thank you @Francisco for your reply. The above method is called for manual session archive. I am using automatic session archive, because of which I can't use startArchive function and fetch archive id.

Comment: Then, you can query this URL:

https://api.opentok.com/v2/project/<api_key>/archive?sessionId=<sessionId>

and you will get a list of archives for that session, with all the information you need.

See https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/, "Automatically archived sessions".